# Del tag work incorrect with self closed paragraph

Tags: html

In the following html code del tag strikethrough next tag:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html 
PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
 <div>
  <del><p /></del>
  <strong>Why is this text marked strikethrough?</strong>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

### How to fix this issue?

Fix1: this issue occured locally with the .html files. Rename file to .xhtml fix this issue.

Fix2: on the server side possible to return correct content-type from webserver.

Comment: This is an html question. This markup will not work as XHTML resource properly served with a content type of `application/xhtml+xml` because the namespace isn't declared. And if the namespace was declared, the text would not be struck out. I have changed the tags appropriately.

Comment: I was added the namespace and xml declaration. Same issue.

Comment: @EminST — Emphasis on content type

Comment: Are you using Windows 95?

Comment: :) No, I had local file with .html extention. Rename to .xhtml fix this issue. However I prefer to stay on the .html extension and still search solution.

Answer (score 1):

You are serving your XHTML document as `text/html` so browsers will parse it according to HTML parsing rules.

The `/` in `<p />` will be treated as an error and discarded, and further error recovery will put the strong element inside the paragraph.

You need to serve the XHTML with a `application/xhtml+xml` content-type HTTP response header for browsers to parse it properly.

---

XHTML is more-or-less dead, especially for use client-side in browsers. Write HTML 5 instead.

Comment: Thank you. I added 2 possible fixes. However I still need to use it in .html extension and locally.

Comment: Then don't use XHTML.